# KonvaJS: How to serialize object with custom property?

Tags: javascript, konvajs

```
var group = new Konva.Group();
group.customProp = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
group.toJSON();
```

Result:

```
{
    attrs: {},
    className: "Group",
    children: []
}
```

And `customProp` is lost.

How can I convert the object to JSON without losing the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties on an instance will be not serialized. You should use public API to set/get properties.

```
var group = new Konva.Group();
group.setAttr('customProp', [1, 2, 3]);
// use this to read property
// group.getAttr('customProp')
group.toJSON();
```

Output:

```
{"attrs":{"customProp":[1,2,3]},"className":"Group","children":[]}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about this method.

Answer (score 0):

var group = new Konva.Group();

Object.defineProperty(group , "customProp" , ['a','b', 'c'])

group.toJSON();

//Look here 
//https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: The result is the same. I suppose it's some specific declaration of KonvaJS objects